# Nokogiri - How to name a node `comment`?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to create some XML:

```
def builder
  Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.foobar do
      xml.comment('Some comment', created_at: Time.zone.now.iso8601)
    end
  end
end
```

I want this structure:

```
<foobar>
  <comment created_at='...'>
   Some comment
  </comment>
</foobar>
```

Unfortunately the Nokogiri DSL won't allow me to name a node `comment` since it's an internal method to create XML-Comments. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder

> Unfortunately some methods are defined in ruby that are difficult or dangerous to remove. You may want to create tags with the name “type”, “class”, and “id” for example. In that case, you can use an underscore to disambiguate your tag name from the method call.

Therefore you need:

```
def builder
  Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.foobar do
      xml.comment_('Some comment', created_at: Time.zone.now.iso8601)
    end
  end
end
```